# One hardware MFA token, multiple accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is it possible to use one hardware MFA device with multiple AWS accounts? E.g. I have 80 accounts and would like to have one token to handle MFA to all of them. Having 80 separate tokens will be tedious and hard to manage.

Logic tells me that this is not possible because you need to add a serial number of a hardware MFA device to the AWS when setting up the MFA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of device.

> Q. Can I use my U2F security key with multiple AWS accounts?
>
> Yes. AWS allows you to use the same U2F security key with several root and IAM users across multiple accounts.
>
> Q. Can I use virtual, hardware, or SMS MFA with multiple AWS accounts?
>
> No. The MFA device or mobile phone number associated to virtual, hardware, and SMS MFA is bound to an individual AWS identity (IAM user or root account). If you have a TOTP-compatible application installed on your smartphone, you can create multiple virtual MFA devices on the same smartphone. Each one of the virtual MFA devices is bound to a single identity, just like hardware MFA (Gemalto) device. If you dissociate (deactivate) the MFA device, you can then reuse it with a different AWS identity. The MFA device associated to hardware MFA cannot currently be used by more than one identity simultaneously.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#MFA_FAQs

Answer (score 1):

> AWS allows you to use the same U2F security key with several root and
>   IAM users across multiple accounts.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/#MFA_FAQs

YubiKey security key (provided by Yubico) is one example - https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there are three ways that allow you to setup root accounts in AWS. [image]

1. **Virtual MFA Device**: This is those authenticator apps that you can find and install from an app store on your device. You can also manage multiple accounts within one app.
2. **U2F Security Key**: U2F is an open authentication standard hosted by the FIDO Alliance and it is a more advanced security protocol. Currently there is only one company called Yubico that supports here. Yubico has many different keys (called YubiKey) that you can plug in and tap to register or authenticate yourself. It also supports multiple accounts per key.
3. **Other Hardware**: This is where Gemalto tokens come into play. The device has a display to show the code that you can authenticate yourself. One key per account which is not so convenient if you need to manage multiple accounts.

One thing I want to point out here is the YubiKey. Although it is an U2F device, it actually can be used as a Virtual MFA Device (sorry that you can only pick one method as AWS allows you to use one way). You simply download an app called Yubico Authenticator. All the accounts (seeds) are planted into the key itself. This means it only shows the related accounts to the key and no more. With this way (YubiKey + Yubico Authenticator), you can even set up one key to one account, one key to multiple accounts, multiple keys to one account, and multiple keys to multiple accounts. To assign one key to multiple account, you just plug in keys while the same QR code is showing, and use the Yubico Authenticator to snap the QR code to assign.